# A dot product of predetermined value with an arbitrary vector

Tags: matrix, vector, product

I've been writing an application that requires to pick a row vector of a matrix that is the closest match to a given vector (let's call it a query vector). Given that both matrix rows and the query vector are normalized to be unit vectors, it seems obvious to me that a simple matrix-vector multiplication will yield a vector of cosine similarities with it's maximum value being the best match I'm looking for.

Now the thing is that this row-picking is running in an iteration in which I pick the best row, use it to recompute the query vector and then, before the next iteration starts, I need to remove the row so it doesn't get picked again (which is likely to happen even despite the query vector recomputation).

I have this algorithm implemented in MATLAB and it's quite easy with all the funky syntax MATLAB has. But I need to do the same in CUDA with speed in mind. The question is simple:

***How to "disable" a row vector of the matrix so it cannot be picked in the next iteration?***

I found several solutions to this:

- copy the remaining rows into a temporary matrix and iterate on that
- in each iteration, fill all the rows to disable with the inverse values of the newly computed query vector (in MATLAB notation, -1 ./ queryVector)
- simply fill the rows with zeros

The first two are a performance blow, the third is a good one, but the problem is that the dot product ranges from -1 to 1 (all vectors can have negative values), not from 0 to 1, leaving space for errorneous picks of null rows.

Given that I'm no math expert, the ultimate question is the following:

**Is there a vector that gives a -1 or less dot product with any arbitrary vector?**

My senses are telling me that there is a nice and elegant solution to this, be it mathematical or algorithmical, but I can't seem to figure it out. Obviously, if you find anything wrong with anything I say above, please let me know.

**EDIT:**

I didn't want to share the code as my I'm implementing this in both MATLAB and CUDA with slight differences, so I wanted to avoid possible confusion. But here it is. This is pretty much the entire algorithm in MATLAB that runs in a loop:

```
    1. alphas = trainingMatrixCopy * residual;            
    2. [~, j] = max(alphas);            
    3. indices(n) = j;
    4. trainingSubMatrix(n, :) = trainingMatrixCopy(j, :);
    5. trainingMatrixCopy(j, :) = 0;
    6. subS = pinv(trainingSubMatrix(1:n, :))' * testingVector';
    7. s(indices(1:n)) = subS;        
    8. residual = testingVector' - trainingSubMatrix(1:n, :)' * subS;
```

With both *trainingMatrixCopy* and *residual* being normalized, *alphas* provide the cosine measures mentioned above. After the recalculation that takes place at the last line, I'd like to make sure that *j*th row of *trainingMatrixCopy* can never be picked again. The 5th line almost ensures that, but not quite. And I'm curious: can the *j*th row be replaced with something that, when multiplied with *residual* at line 1, will result in -1 or less?

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: show us some code, what have you done already?, beside where are you trying to do this? Matlab? Maple? c++?

Comment: Added some MATLAB code, hope it helps understand what I'm trying to achieve.